# Why does Rails 6.0.x respond with html when a json view is available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Rails 5.2 will correctly respond with a `json` view implicitly when the accept header is `application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01` and `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`.

In Rails 6 the `html` template is rendered instead. The way around this is to add this to the controller method:

```
def show
  ...
  respond_to :html, :json
end
```

I'd rather not do this since Rails already knows there's a `show.html.erb` and a `show.json.jbuilder` view available.

Does anyone know what changed to cause this, and if it's possible to still achieve an implicit view render?

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by adding this to your `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` file:

```rb
Mime::Type.register "*/*", :all
```

**This is also fixed in Rails 6.1.**